Using Reduce to Eliminate a trig variable
Trying to eliminate th from two equations but not correctly getting to use Reduce from a simple pair of equations:
eq = {2 a Sec[2 th] Sin[th] == rho Sin[ph], 
  4 a^2 Tan[2 th]^2 == rho^2 + 2 a rho Cos[ph]}
Eliminate[eq, th]
Reduce[ eq, {th, 0, Pi/2}, {th}]

Thanks for help.

The syntax for elimination with Reduce[] is Reduce[eq, {}, {th}]. But given the warning message from Eliminate, you may want to specify a domain for th.

Thanks; edited as above.

As usual for trigonometric equations, I suggest you use a Weierstraß substitution:
eq2 = TrigExpand[eq] /. {Sin[th] -> (2 t)/(1 + t^2),
                         Cos[th] -> (1 - t^2)/(1 + t^2),
                         Sin[ph] -> (2 p)/(1 + p^2),
                         Cos[ph] -> (1 - p^2)/(1 + p^2)} // FullSimplify
(*    {(2 a t (1 + t^2))/(1 - 6 t^2 + t^4) == (p rho)/(1 + p^2),
       (64 a^2 t^2 (-1 + t^2)^2)/(1 - 6 t^2 + t^4)^2 == rho (a (-2 + 4/(1 + p^2)) + rho)}    *)

Solve[eq2, {t, p}] // FullSimplify
(* 16 rather lengthy solutions *)


I think this variant gives the OP what they asked for: eq2 = TrigExpand[eq] /. {Sin[th] -> (2 t)/(1 + t^2), Cos[th] -> (1 - t^2)/(1 + t^2)} // FullSimplify; Eliminate[eq2, t] and very nicely. (+1)

@Roman: Thanks! That simplifies a lot !

This gives a long output after a dozen seconds:
eq = {2 a Sec[2 th] Sin[th] == rho Sin[ph], 
   4 a^2 Tan[2 th]^2 == rho^2 + 2 a rho Cos[ph]};
 Reduce[Join[eq, {0 <= th < 2 Pi}], {Sin[ph], Cos[ph]}, {th}, Reals]

You might want to examine the output and decide what restriction you might want to impose on the variables.

But with Weierstrass and Eliminate the constant $a$ has disappeared without setting it equal to $1! $
Further simplifies without dimension tally with $a$ as $(-16 - 4 \rho^2 - 8 \rho \cos[\phi]) \sin[\phi]^2 +
4 \rho^3 \sin[\phi]^4 =
(-4 - \rho^2 - 8 \cos[\phi]/\rho - 4 \rho \cos[\phi] -    4  \cos[\phi]^2)$

@Narasimham I thought you were asking about the syntax of Reduce[], which I was showing above along with a random hypothesis that enables Reduce[] to work.  I guess you're replying to my comment below Roman's answer? In any case, the a does not disappear for me in any of the methods.
